# How to print mensagens in the source code of the page using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf, jsp-tags

This is my code using jsp and jstl:

```
 <!-- 
        Failed to access a URL: ${url}
        Exception: ${exception}
     -->
```

How to do the same using Thymeleaf?
This code below dont work:

```
  <--  <p>Failed to access a URL: <span  th:text="${ url}"></span></p> 
    <p>Exception: <span th:text="${exception}"></span></p> -->
```

When I do not comment  it show the message on page:

> Failed to access a URL:
>   http://localhost:8080/blog-spring-thymeleaf/auth/login
>
> Exception: org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No
>   handler found for GET /blog-spring-thymeleaf/auth/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *inlined expressions*, double brackets:

```html
<!-- 
        Failed to access a URL: [[${url}]]
        Exception: [[${exception}]]
    -->
```

Comment: Thanks , this help so much!!